# Query with EXCEPT throws an error

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL keeps throwing errors when I try to use the SQL `except` in my query...

Why isn't it working? What's wrong with it?

```
select name, email from users
except
select name, email from users_ban
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know MySQL does not support the`except`statement. You can use query with a correlated`not exists`predicate to the same effect like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM users
  WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
                    SELECT 1
                      FROM users_ban
                      WHERE users.name
                            = 
                            users_ban.name
                        AND users.email
                            = 
                            users_ban.email );
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/057680/1)